# How to get a prediction interval instead of point estimate for regression in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I am working on a housing price regression problem using sklearn. Is there any way we can get a prediction range instead of point estimate using Linear Regression etc.

Comment: You can look into Bayesian Linear Regression, which is a slightly different framework, where you assume a prior for the parameters.